# Setting OnItemClick to open URL in webview for rss feed

Tags: android, listview, rss, xml-parsing

I know I'm over looking this or over thinking this but I can not seem to figure out how to launch the link of an rss feed when the user clicks it.  I'm using a DOM Parser to parse the xml file into a listview and get all the info from the xml file.  The problem I'm having is parsing it into a Custom WebActivity that i have that should load a webview client that i have as well.  Here is the code i'm working with.

Main Activity

```
 public class CustomizedListView extends Activity {
// All static variables
static final String URL = "http://treymorgan.net/feed";
// XML node keys
static final String KEY_ITEM = "item"; // parent node 
static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_PUB_DATE = "pubDate";
static final String KEY_LINK = "guid";

ListView list;
LazyAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
    // looping through all song nodes <song>
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
        map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
        map.put(KEY_PUB_DATE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_PUB_DATE));
        map.put(KEY_LINK, parser.getValue(e, KEY_LINK));

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        songsList.add(map);
    }


    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
    adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);        
    list.setAdapter(adapter);


    // Click event for single list row
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
```

EDIT :  This is the section of code i'm haveing trouble with ... the onItemClick method to send the url from the rss feed to the webview activity so that it can be viewed in app and not through the native browser on the device

```
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(CustomizedListView.this, WebviewActivity.class);  
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            intent.putExtra("KEY_LINK", b);
            startActivity(intent); 



             }

    });
}   
 }
```

here is my Webview activity

```
 public class WebviewActivity extends Activity{
  private WebView webview;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);

    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras(); 
    String KEY_LINK = b.getString("KEY_LINK");

    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient(this));
    webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
    webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webview.setInitialScale(1);
    webview.loadUrl(KEY_LINK);



  }


       }
```

So basicly, what I'm wanting to do is String the KEY_GUID to the WebviewActivity and I can't seem to figure out how to recive the string from one activity to the other.  Thanks in advance for any help

EDIT:  OK I've worked on this a while and I have updated the code i'm using that is relevent to this issue.  Now I have no errors and when i click an item it will open the WebviewActivity but it does not load the website nor does it attach my webview client to it either.  Can anyone help me figure this out?

EDIT:
when i load the code like this:

```
 @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(CustomizedListView.this,    WebviewActivity.class);  
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            intent.putExtra("b", "http://www.google.com" );
            startActivity(intent);
```

It opens the webview activity and loads google up just fine.  So maybe the problem i am having now is how to get the link that i need from my DOM parser.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: does the variable KEY_LINK get the value you are passing?

Comment: It should be getting the value yes unless I have forgotten something to make it get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is the answer to my question i asked.  This worked great for me and did exactly as i wanted.  Here is the working code for it

```
 public class CustomizedListView extends Activity {
// All static variables
static final String URL = "http://treymorgan.net/feed";
// XML node keys
static final String KEY_ITEM = "item"; // parent node 
static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_PUB_DATE = "pubDate";
static final String KEY_LINK = "link";

ListView list;
LazyAdapter adapter;

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
    // looping through all song nodes <song>
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ITEM));
        map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
        map.put(KEY_PUB_DATE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_PUB_DATE));
        map.put(KEY_LINK, parser.getValue(e, KEY_LINK));

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        songsList.add(map);
    }


    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
    adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);        
    list.setAdapter(adapter);


    // Click event for single list row
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(CustomizedListView.this, WebviewActivity.class);  
            new Bundle();
            intent.putExtra( "b", songsList.get(position).get(KEY_LINK));
            startActivity(intent); 



             }

    });
}   
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your calling activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, WebActivity.class);
i.putExtra(MY_KEY, "http://http://stackoverflow.com");
startActivity(i);
```

In your receiving activity:

```
protected void onStart() {
  super.onStart();
  String myUrl = getExtras().getString(MY_KEY);
  webView.loadUrl(myUrl);
}
```

---

**Edit:**

Assuming your adapter contains HashMaps (from what I see on how you parse your XML)

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
  HashMap<String, String> selectedSong = (HashMap<String, String>) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

  Intent intent = new Intent(CustomizedListView.this, WebviewActivity.class);  
  intent.putExtra("KEY_LINK", selectedSong.get(KEY_LINK));
  startActivity(intent); 
}
```

Comment: Hardcoding the url doesn't help any with this because the url is being pulled from the xml file so i don't have the url to hardcode.  I need it to examine the xml file and get the url and string it into the next class

Comment: Do I need to change anything in the webview class

Comment: Have you at least tried it? That's my last edit to that answer, you got to put some effort into it. Don't expect others to code for you.

Comment: I am going to try it, i'm at work right now and not at my computer yet, I was just asking, it will be this evening before I will know if it works

Answer (score 0):

For the pass string from one activity to the other

**First activity:**

```
Intent indisplay = new Intent(FirstClass.this,SecondClass.class);
indisplay.putExtra("link",your link here);
startActivity(indisplay);
```

**Second activity:**

```
 Intent indispaly = getIntent();
 String url = indispaly.getStringExtra("link");
    // your link from previous activity is stored into the url
```

And for display into **webview**,Like:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.newsdisplay);
    getWindow().setFeatureInt( Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON); 


    Intent indispaly = getIntent();
    String url = indispaly.getStringExtra("link");

    newswebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.news_webView);
    newswebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    WebSettings webSettings = newswebview.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    newswebview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);       //Zoom Control on web (You don't need this 
     //if ROM supports Multi-Touch      
    newswebview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true); //Enable Multitouch if supported by ROM


    newswebview.loadUrl(url);


    final Activity MyActivity = this;


newswebview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) 
       {

        //Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded, and changes string to Loading...
        MyActivity.setTitle("  Loading...");
        MyActivity.setProgress(progress * 100); //Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded

        // Return the app name after finish loading
           if(progress == 100){

               MyActivity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);

           }


    }
});

}

 @Override  
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)   
    {  
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && newswebview.canGoBack()) {  
            newswebview.goBack();  
            return true;  
        }  
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);  
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will give this a try, however i think when you posted this i was in the process of editing my original question to better specify what i'm needing, do you think this will still work after the edits i just made to the question